# Странная ошибка в MonthCalendar

Tags: .net, winforms

Несколько дней назад стала появляться странная ошибка в компоненте MonthCalendar.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
   at System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Система Windows 7, .Net Framework 4.0

Программа не менялась уже много лет и прекрасно работала, и вдруг начала падать при выборе даты в календаре.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным? Может Microsoft какое-то обновление выкатил, которое рушит календарь?

Вот у человека похоже аналогичная проблема:
[Strange error in MonthCalendar just started happening out of nowhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30262731/strange-error-in-monthcalendar-just-started-happening-out-of-nowhere)

Answer (score 1):

Проблема возникает при установке свойства `BoldDates` в массив дат вместо добавления `BoldDates` по одной. Судя по всему, проявляется после установки апдейта KB3023222.

```
this.monthCalendar1.BoldedDates = 
    new DateTime[] { new DateTime(2015, 04, 01), new DateTime(2015, 04, 02) };
```

Хотфикс .NET для этого креша:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3064711 (Offline) 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3064715 (Web)

> Problems solved:
>
> Assume that you are running a Windows Forms application. When the application disposes a System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar control in certain cases, the following InvalidOperationException exception will be thrown:
> *Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.*

Этот баг на MS Connect:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1345128/errors-after-installing-kb3023222-update